# Apply list to arguments in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How would I go about applying each element in a list to each argument in a function? Kind of like `Map`, except with a variable number of arguments.

So for example, if I have a function `action[x1_,x2_,x3_]:=...`, and I have a list `{1,2,3}`, how would I create a function to call `action` with `action[1,2,3]`?

I would like this function be able to handle me changing `action` to `action[x1_,x2]`, and anything else, also, with the list now being `{1,2}`, and to call action now with `action[1,2]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on "Kind of like Map, except with a variable number of arguments." I think you might be looking for `Apply` to level 1.  This is done with:

```
Apply[function, array, {1}]
```

or the shorthand:

```
function @@@ array
```

Here is what it does:

```
array = {{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}, {Pi, Sin, Tan}};

action @@@ array
```

```
   {action[1, 2, 3], action[a, b, c], action[Pi, Sin, Tan]}
```

---

The terminology I used above could be misleading, and limits the power of `Apply`.  The expression to which you apply `action` does not need to be a rectangular array.  It does not even need to be a `List`: `{...}` or have its elements be lists.  Here is an example incorporating these possibilities:

```
args = {1, 2} | f[a, b, c] | {Pi};

action @@@ args
```

```
   action[1, 2] | action[a, b, c] | action[Pi]
```

- `args` is not a `List` but a set of `Alternatives`
- the number of arguments passed to `action` varies
- one of the elements of `args` has head `f`

Observe that:

- `action` replaces the head of each element of `args`, whatever it may be.
- The head of `args` is preserved in the output, in this case `Alternatives` (short form: `a | b | c`)

Comment: what is the difference between your solution and Sasha's? I mean, I see `@@@` in yours and only `@@` in his. How can they both be the same?

Comment: @d'o-o'b they are not the same, but they are for the same function: `Apply`.  `f @@ {1,2,3}` gives `f[1,2,3]` in effect replacing `List` with `f` at "Level 0" (the top level of `{1,2,3}`).  By contrast, `f @@@ {{1}, {2}, {3}}` gives {f[1], f[2], f[3]}, replacing `List` with `f` for each _element_ of the list, or "Level 1."  This can also be done for deeper levels of an expression using `Apply[f, expression, levelspec]` but there is no shorthand (like `@@` or `@@@`) for this.  See the help on `Level` for details of levelspec.

Answer (score 9):

```
Apply[action, {1,2,3}]
```

This also can be entered as `action @@ {1,2,3}`.

Answer (score -2):

Why not just use action[lst_?ListQ]?

Comment: Is this the question you meant to answer?