# How to remove the extra {} when Mapping a function to a list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Simple question, given a list like this

```
Clear[a, b, c, d, e, f];
lst = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
```

and suppose I have a function defined like this:

```
foo[x_,y_]:=Module[{},...]
```

And I want to apply this function to the list, so If I type

```
Map[foo, lst]
```

This gives

```
{foo[{a, b}], foo[{c, d}], foo[{e, f}]}
```

I want it to come out as

```
{foo[a, b], foo[c, d], foo[e, f]}
```

so it works.

What is the best way to do this? Assume I can't modify the function foo[] definition (say it is build-in)

Only 2 ways I know now are

```
Map[foo[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &, lst]
{foo[a, b], foo[c, d], foo[e, f]}
```

(too much work), or

```
MapThread[foo, Transpose[lst]]
{foo[a, b], foo[c, d], foo[e, f]}
```

(less typing, but need to transpose first)

Question: Any other better ways to do the above? I looked at other Map and its friends, and I could not see a function to do it more directly than what I have.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5746717/499167) question:  **Apply list to arguments in Mathematica**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need `Apply` at `Level` 1 or its short form, `@@@`

```
foo@@@lst    
{foo[a, b], foo[c, d], foo[e, f]}
```

Answer (score 7):

One possible way is to change head of each element of `lst` from `List` to `foo`:

```
foo @@ # & /@ lst
{foo[a, b], foo[c, d], foo[e, f]}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just to report puzzling performance tests of the both methods (`@@@`, `@@ # & /@`) :

```
        T = RandomReal[{1,100}, {1000000, 2}];

        H[F_Symbol, T_List] := 

                     First@AbsoluteTiming[F @@@ T;]/First@AbsoluteTiming[F @@ # & /@ T;]

        Table[{ToString[F], H[F, T]},  {F, {Plus, Subtract, Times, Divide, Power, Log}}]

Out[3]= {{"Plus",     4.174757}, 
         {"Subtract", 0.2596154}, 
         {"Times",    3.928230}, 
         {"Divide",   0.2674164}, 
         {"Power",    0.3148629},
         {"Log",      0.2986936}}
```

These results are not random, but roughly proportional for very different data sizes.

`@@@` is roughly 3-4 times faster for `Subtract`, `Divide`, `Power`, `Log`  while `@@ # & /@` is 4 times faster for `Plus` and `Times` giving rise to another questions, which (as one can believe) could be slightly
clarified by the following evaluation:

```
 Attributes@{Plus, Subtract, Times, Divide, Power, Log}
```

Only `Plus` and `Times` have attributes `Flat` and `Orderless`, while among the rest only `Power` (which seems relatively the most efficient there) has also an attribute  `OneIdentity`.

**Edit**

A reliable explanation to observed performance boosts (thanks to Leonid Shifrin's remarks)  should go along a different route.

By default there is `MapCompileLength -> 100` as we can check evaluating `SystemOptions["CompileOptions"]`.
To reset autocompilation of Map we can evaluate :

```
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "MapCompileLength" -> Infinity]
```

Now we can test relative performance of the both methods by evaluating once more our `H` - performance testing function on related symbols and list :

```
          Table[{ToString[F], H[F, T]}, {F, {Plus, Subtract, Times, Divide, Power, Log}}]

 Out[15]= {{"Plus",      0.2898246},
           {"Subtract",  0.2979452}, 
           {"Times",     0.2721893}, 
           {"Divide",    0.3078512}, 
           {"Power",     0.3321622},
           {"Log",       0.3258972}}
```

Having these result we can conclude that in general Yoda's approach (`@@@`) is the most efficient, while that provided by Andrei is better in case of `Plus` and `Times` due to automatic compilation of `Map` allowing better performance of (`@@ # & /@`).

Comment: Not so puzzling if we recall that `Map` autocompiles when it can, and `Apply` can be compiled for just 3 heads: `Plus`, `Times` and `List`. OTOH, `@@@` does not autocompile. You see efficiency boosts for `Plus` and `Times` due to autocompilation in the `@@#&/@` construct, and because your input is a large packed array (which allows one to benefit from autocompilation)

Comment: See also this answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405304/memory-use-of-apply-vs-map-virtual-memory-use-and-lock-ups/6408489#6408489, and the comments below it, for more discussion of similar matters.

Comment: @Leonid   Thank You for interesting link and comments.  Indeed, when I evaluate  my `H` function on `T1 = FromPackedArray[T]`  relative efficiency of  `Plus` and `Times` slows down roughly by the factor 2, while the other functions only by a few percents,  however `Map` is still almost two times faster for `Plus` and `Times`.  The reason of this effect is apparently  autocompilation.  On the other hand, remarks on Attributes of related functions are still valid and I hope there  shouldn't be any kind of misunderstanding.

Comment: Frankly, I think that autocompilation is the *sole* reason for the performance difference, while other attributes you mention don't contribute to it in this particular case. To see that, execute `SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "MapCompileLength" -> Infinity]` - this effectively disables auto-compilation. Then redo your timings and you will see that `Times` and `Plus` now behave the same as the rest (make sure to restore "MapCompileLength" to its default (100)).To be sure, attributes can make a difference, but not in this case I guess.

Comment: Thank You for helpful comments.  What to do in case one would like to set permanently different MapCompileLength, ...Option Inspector ? I guess this is not recommended. Have you tried to do it ?

Comment: To downvoter,  Could you be more specific what is wrong in my answer, or what can be improved ?

Comment: I actually never tried to change that option globally. One thing you can do is to put the `SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "MapCompileLength" -> your value]` line in your `init.m` (the one for the kernel). But, why bother? The default seems very sensible, and why would you want to change it? The compilation is to byte-code, and does not take that much time, while generally improves code efficiency.

Comment: It is not my intention to change default values of SystemOptions, but I wondered what to do in case of a need.  Conditionally, as one could deduce from my post, it would be helpful in  certain serious computational tasks.

Comment: The only route to change these I am aware of is through `SetSystemOptions`. May be there are other ways.

Answer (score 4):

A few more possibilities to pick from:

This one is a more verbose version of yoda's answer. It applies `foo` at level 1 of the list `lst` only (replaces the head `List` with the head `foo`):

```
Apply[foo, lst, {1}]
```

This does the same, but maps `Apply` over the list `lst` (essentially Andrei's answer):

```
Map[Apply[foo, #] &, lst ]
```

And this just replaces the pattern List[x__] with foo[x] at level 1:

```
Replace[lst, List[x__] -> foo[x], 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

The answers on `Apply[]` are spot on, and is the right thing to do, but what you were trying to do, was to replace a `List[]` head with a `Sequence[]` head, i.e. `List[List[3,5],List[6,7]]` should become `List[Sequence[3,5],Sequence[6,7]]`.

Sequence head is what naturally remains if a head of any list of parameters is deleted, so `Delete[Plus[3,5],0]` and `Delete[{3,5},0]` and `Delete[List[3,5],0]` would all produce `Sequence[3,5]`.

So `foo@Delete[#,0]&/@{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}` will give you the same as `foo@@@{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}`.

Alternatively, `foo[#/.List->Sequence]&/@{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}` does the same thing.

Comment: I have to disagree with the statement that he wants to turn `List[List[...] ..]` into `List[Sequence[...] ..]`. More correctly, he wants `List[f[...] ..]`, i.e. he wants to change the heads of the inner lists to `f`.

Comment: I agree that this is what he ultimately "wants". I meant to say it in a sense "what you want to do to get there is..." ;-) Sorry for the confusion. To get to `List[f[Sequence[...]], ...]` he needed a way to convert a list of lists to a list of sequences. Apply does it internally.